# How can a class method affect an instance of a class created by another method?

Tags: python, class, oop

As an example, I created a Page class, it has a method for creating an input field and a button. In the button I want to put a command to clear the input field.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page:

    window = tk.Tk()

    def start(self):
        Page.window.mainloop()
   
    def entry_win(self, row_lbl: int, colm_lbl: int):  
        self.row_lbl = row_lbl
        self.colm_lbl = colm_lbl
        
        entry = tk.Entry(Page.window,...)
        entry.grid(row=row_lbl, column=colm_lbl)

    def btn_win(self, txt: str, row_lbl: int, colm_lbl: int, command_is ):
        self.txt_lbl = txt_lbl
        self.row_lbl = row_lbl
        self.colm_lbl = colm_lbl
        self.command_is = command_is
        
        btn = tk.Button(StartPage.window,..., command=command_is)
        btn.grid(row=row_lbl, column=colm_lbl)

page = Page()

entry_field = page.entry_win(0, 0)
btn_cleaner = page.btn_win(some_txt, 1, 0, command_is )

page.start()
```

As a command_is variable, I want to use a function that will clear the created input fields.
I don't quite understand how to do this at all. Create a method inside a class? But how will it affect the local variable of another method, which in fact does not exist.

I tried to create a function outside the class.

```
import tkinter as tk

def cleaner():
    entry_field.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_field.insert(0, "")

class Page:
    ...

page = Page()

entry_field = page.entry_win(0, 0)
btn_cleaner = page.btn_win(some_txt, 1, 0, cleaner)

page.start()
```

But it didn't work.
Is it even possible to do this? And if so, where am I wrong and what could I do?

Comment: `entry` shouldn't be local but an instance variable (with `self.`) or `return`ed to be accessible from outside of `entry_win`.

Answer (score 2):

You should point to the class instance of the entry, using the `self` pointer.
Here is an example of how you could do this.

```
class Page:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()

    def start(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
   
    def entry_win(self, row_lbl: int, colm_lbl: int):  
        self.row_lbl = row_lbl
        self.colm_lbl = colm_lbl
        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.window,...)
        self.entry.grid(row=row_lbl, column=colm_lbl)
        
    def clear_entry(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, "")

    def btn_win(self, txt: str, row_lbl: int, colm_lbl: int, command_is ):
        self.txt_lbl = txt_lbl
        self.row_lbl = row_lbl
        self.colm_lbl = colm_lbl
        self.command_is = command_is
        
        btn = tk.Button(StartPage.window,..., command=command_is)
        btn.grid(row=row_lbl, column=colm_lbl)
```

Now to call your `Page` you must initialize it like so `Page()`

I hope I understood your problem and this helps!

Comment: Did I understand correctly: I pointed to the instance of the class through `self`, then created the button and passed the command to it: `btn_cleaner = page.btn_win(some_txt, 1, 0, Page.clear_entry) `
When I click the button I get an error: `TypeError: StartPage.throw_off() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Yes this is normal, I forgot to implement it, You need a constructor for your class, I will correct my code snippet.

Comment: I added a constructor, but the error was not resolved. Now I refer everywhere to the instance of the class, via self, instead of specifying the class itself (like: `self.window`, not `Page.window`)

Comment: How do I correctly understand the difference between calling through `self` and `Page`? `self` globalizes variables inside my class, and `Page` allows you to get only what is in its attributes or access the method?

Comment: I can throw off my code in its original form, maybe I'm missing something when correcting the code for asking a question